# How to deploy JBoss Fuse profile to multiple containers?

Tags: jbossfuse

I have created Fabric with one server and joined the another server with this fabric.   I have root and root1 containers respectively.

How do I deploy the profile in these two containers or child containers (cont1 in box1server and cont2 in box2server) at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

From web-console: you go to the profiles page and then use the assign button to choose the containers.

From terminal:

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> fabric:container-change-profile child2 yourprofile
JBossFuse:karaf@root> fabric:container-change-profile child3 yourprofile
JBossFuse:karaf@root>
```

Monitor the log files for the child containers on the second and third node to make sure that
the application has been successfully deployed. These log files will be located at:

Node2: jboss-fuse/instances/child2/data/log/karaf.log

Node3: jboss-fuse/instances/child3/data/log/karaf.log